# How to optymalize iteration by list and calling method

Tags: java, optimization, lambda, java-stream, refactoring

I would like to optymalize my process of iteration by list and filltering it.
For example:
I have a short list of some similar objects where the difference will be one field:

```
List<ObjTest> objects = getListOfObjects();
```

Next, I would like to check if list is not empty and iter by each object, compare fields with input andi if fields will match I would like to call methodA. Otherwise, when fields of objects not match I would like to call after iteration methodB.

Something like:

```
for (ObjTest objTest : objects) {
    if (objTest.getField().equals(input.getField()) {
        return methodA(input);
    }
}
return methodB(input)
```

Is it possible to do by objects.stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anyMatch()`:

```
if (objects.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getField().equals(input.getField()))) {
    return methodA(input);
} else {
    return methodB(input);
}
```

Comment: thanks man, Thats what I expected.... I have huge problems with streams...

Comment: I’d probably avoid repeating the `input.getField()` call for every element: `var inputField = input.getField(); return objects.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getField().equals(inputField))? methodA(input): methodB(input);` Or capture the value with a method reference: `return objects.stream().map(ObjTest::getField).anyMatch(input.getField()::equals)? methodA(input): methodB(input);`

Comment: @Holger I was going to do the latter, but this way was shorter, arguably more readable, and safer (in case `input.getField()` is nullable).

Comment: Since both, the original variant and your variant, assume that `o.getField()` is never `null`, it would be weird to assume that `input.getField()` could be `null`. But *if* that’s possible, I’d add another pre-check as there is no point in iterating over the entire list when the test can never succeed.

Comment: @Holger Sure, but that's true for OP's example too. My point is this is slightly more faithful to the original logic.