# How to rewrite a Java for loop which returns a matching element using streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, refactoring

I would like to optymalize my method.

I have list of objects and I would like to iter by them, compare fields with input and in case of match I would like to use that first object in other method. Something like:

```
for (ObjTest objTest : listOfObjTest) {
    if (objTest.getField().equals(input.getField()) {
       return methodA(input, objTest);
    }
}
return methodB(input);
```

I was trying to do it with `findFirst` but I do not know how to call that

```
listOfObjTest.stream().filter(obj -> Objects.equals(objTest.getField(), input.getField())).findFirst().get();
```

Do you recommend any tutorial for lambdas and streams becouse I have a lot of problems when I have to create something new...

Comment: optymalize doesn't seem to be a valid Engilsh word.

Comment: This seems very similar to [another question you asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76267546/12567365). If you are just looking for `findFirst` examples, there are [several](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+stream+findfirst+site:stackoverflow.com) you can research.

Comment: If you are trying to optimize your example  for *speed* , using streams is not going to make it any faster.

Comment: What do you want to get out of **"optimization"** here? Re-writing a more traditional loop as a stream is not necessarily an optimization - in fact, in some cases it may be the opposite (in terms of readability and maintainability of your code, for example).

Comment: *"Do you recommend any tutorial for lambdas and streams ..."* - No we don't.  Recommendations for this kind of thing are off-topic.  (But Google for "java streams tutorial oracle" ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend *Java 8 Lambdas* by O'Reilly Media.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-8-lambdas/9781449370831/

It offers a wealth of information, including the topic your discussing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stream-based equivalent to the code you've written:

```java
return listOfObjTest.stream()
        .filter(objTest -> objTest.getField().equals(input.getField()))
        .findFirst()
        .map(objTest -> methodA(input, objTest))
        .orElseGet(() -> methodB(input));
```

This converts the list to a stream, filters the list to only contain elements that match your condition, returns the first such element, and then calls `methodA` on the element if such an element existed, or `methodB` if it didn't.

With variables to make the types explicit, this is the same as:

```java
List<ObjTest> listOfObjTest = ...
Stream<ObjTest> stream = listOfObjTest.stream();
Stream<ObjTest> filteredSteam = 
        stream.filter(objTest -> objTest.getField().equals(input.getField()));
Optional<ObjTest> firstMatch = filteredStream.findFirst();
Optional<String> matchingField =
        firstMatch.map(objTest -> methodA(input, objTest));
String result = firstMatch.orElseGet(() -> methodB(input));
return result;
```

### Walkthrough

The following is a step-by-step walkthrough of the approach.

1. Start with a list of elements.

   ```java
   List<ObjTest> listOfObjTest = ...;
   ```
2. Convert the list to a stream using [`Collection.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()).

   ```java
   Stream<ObjTest> stream = listOfObjTest.stream();
   ```
3. Filter the stream so it only contains those elements whose `getField` value is equal to `input.getField`, using [`Stream.filter(Predicate predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)).

   ```java
   // Stream<ObjTest>
   Stream<ObjTest> filteredSteam = 
           stream.filter(objTest -> objTest.getField().equals(input.getField()));
   ```
4. Use [`Stream.findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) to return an optional containing the first element remaining in the filtered stream, or an empty optional if no elements matched the filter condition.

   ```java
   Optional<ObjTest> firstMatch = filteredStream.findFirst();
   ```
5. Map the optional, if a value is present, to the result of `methodA` using [`Optional.map(Function mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)).

   ```java
   Optional<String> matchingField =
           firstMatch.map(objTest -> methodA(input, objTest));
   ```
6. Return the matching field value if present, else return the result of `methodB`, using [`Optional.orElseGet(Supplier supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)).

   ```java
   String result = firstMatch.orElseGet(() -> methodB(input));
   ```